# Mimic Stack Overflow's focus/jump to a section and fade from yellow highlight effect using Django

Tags: python, django, get, django-views

I like SO's effect on when you click a notification from the top-left where it says "Stack Exchange", then the SO will open a new page, jump to the specific section, then highlight the section in yellow and fade out.

Currently I have a comment form that is on the bottom of a long website. And when the comment posting fails the validation, I have jQuery to scroll to the form and do the same yellow highlight effect as SO.

Here is my (perfectly working) code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    {% if focus %}
        // Focus
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#{{ focus }}').offset().top }, 'slow')
        $('#{{ focus }}').effect("highlight", {}, 3000)
    {% endif %}
})
```

I have this code in my `base.html` so every template checks for a template variable called `focus`. `focus` is simply a string that holds the `id` of the `<div>` to do the yellow highlight effect.

As you can see I feel this is a bit *hacked*. I need to pass `focus` in a dictionary using `render()` in Django's `views.py`.

What I *really* want to do is pass it as a `GET` variable. Something like `http://www.example.com/orders/2/?focus=comment_form`. Then I can [get that `GET` variable using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) and do the highlight effect. But I don't know how to pass a `GET` variable using `render()`.

Currently my `render()` looks like this:

```
dictionary = get_orders_detail_dictionary(order=order, user=request.user, comment_form=form)
dictionary['focus'] = 'comment_form'
return render(request, 'doors/orders/detail.html', dictionary)
```

The reason I want to use a `GET` is for like "permalinking" options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a GET variable, it's available from `request.GET`. And since you're using the `render` shortcut, you can enable the [`request` context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) to make the `request` object available in your templates, at which point you can just do `{{ request.GET.focus }}`.

However, to me a better option would be to use your own custom context processor which extracts the focus param into a context variable:

```
def get_focus(request):
    return {'focus': request.GET.get('focus', '')}
```

and then you can use `{{ focus }}` exactly as you do now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess here is the stupid question: How do I add a `GET` variable to the `render` shortcut? Currently I only know how to pass template variable as a dictionary.

Comment: That question makes no sense at all, sorry. I've shown you how to pass the template variable via a context processor, I really can't imagine what else you're asking.

Comment: Well I'm reading the ["Request and response objects" documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/) and from what I read it seems like you do something like `request.GET = QueryDict('focus=comment_form')` then do `render(request, 'doors/orders/detail.html', dictionary)` to add a `GET` variable to `request`?

Comment: Still can't see what that is supposed to achieve. Changing that parameter won't affect what your Javascript sees in any way, since the Javascript runs on the client and looks at the actual URL of the page. But since your URL already has `?focus=comment_form` the Javascript wil already be able to see that.